# UIPageViewController en Swift

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode

Hola estoy siguiendo un tutorial sobre UIPageViewController para generar una galeria de imagenes en mi proyecto http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/easy-steps-to-implement-uipageviewcontroller-in-swift incluso baje el demo y funciona pero en mi caso me da un error y se cae la aplicacion.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

adjunto el codigo de mis controladores.

PageContentViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class PageContentViewController: UIPageViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


    var pageIndex: Int = 0
    var strTitle: String!
    var strPhotoName: String!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        imageView.image = UIImage(named: strPhotoName)
        lblTitle.text = strTitle

    }
}
```

ViewController2.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{
    var arrPageTitle: NSArray = NSArray()
    var arrPagePhoto: NSArray = NSArray()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        arrPageTitle = ["This is The App Guruz", "This is Table Tennis 3D", "This is Hide Secrets"];
        arrPagePhoto = ["1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"];

        self.dataSource = self

        self.setViewControllers([getViewControllerAtIndex(0)] as [UIViewController], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    // MARK:- UIPageViewControllerDataSource Methods

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let pageContent: PageContentViewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController

        var index = pageContent.pageIndex

        if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound))
        {
            return nil
        }

        index -= 1;
        return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?
    {
        let pageContent: PageContentViewController = viewController as! PageContentViewController

        var index = pageContent.pageIndex

        if (index == NSNotFound)
        {
            return nil;
        }

        index += 1;
        if (index == arrPageTitle.count)
        {
            return nil;
        }
        return getViewControllerAtIndex(index)
    }

    // MARK:- Other Methods
    func getViewControllerAtIndex(index: NSInteger) -> PageContentViewController
    {
        // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
        let pageContentViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageContentViewController") as! PageContentViewController

        pageContentViewController.strTitle = "\(arrPageTitle[index])"
        pageContentViewController.strPhotoName = "\(arrPagePhoto[index])"
        pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index

        return pageContentViewController
    }



}
```

Comment: Donde tenes el IBOutlet el círculo en la izquierda está lleno o vacío? Si está vacío has la connection con control drag

Answer (score 0):

El error lo tienes o bien en la conexión del outlet de `imageView` que no es correcto o bien en que `strPhotoName` está vació (es `nil`) i la imagen no se carga correctamente.

**Actualización 1**
Después de revisar el código y como he comentado, el problema está en el `UIImageView`. Al instanciar el `PageContentViewController` la propiedad `imageView == nil`. Hay que revisar las conexiones y el storyboard para ver que está fallando. En la siguiente imagen se puede ver el problema con un simple `breakpoint`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización 2**

En [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321383/iboutlet-is-nil-but-it-is-connected-in-storyboard-swift) enlace se puede ver un posible solución al problema.

Comment: ya probe recreando el outlet y la variable strPhotoname debería estar ok ya que en el demo funciona. gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Asegurate haciendo un `print(strPhotoname)` antes de asignar la imagen al `UIImageview`. Es lo único que podría ser si el outlet es correcto. Aún así, ¿podrías subir el proyecto a Dropbox o similar para echarle un vistazo en su conjunto?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/qurg5vmf8m57ovm/AAAhqkHhr2rJiIyAXNqLjBTBa?dl=0 ahi esta el projecto se agradece cualquier ayuda.

Comment: falta el archivo `*.xcodeproj`. Haz un ZIP mejor con todo...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sb6t9p2tbte44yg/Patagonia%20Viva.zip?dl=0

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, como te decía, revisa bien el `UIImageView`

Comment: mmm... un poco complicado no manejo mucho el programa ni el lenguaje empecé hace poco veré que puedo hacer gracias de todos modos.

Comment: He vuelto a actualizar la respuesta

Comment: cuando seguí el tutorial, cree el ViewController2.swift en el tutorial usaban ViewController.swift puede que al crear uno nuevo y agregar el código del tutorial alguna referencia al VC este mal echa ? puede ser eso lo que causa el error?

Comment: intenta inyectar el dato desde un init, para la imagen y el texto o un configView(image: UIImage, text: String) este caso creo es el pageContent, veo que hay dos arreglos uno para la imagen y otro para el text, no lo veo muy factible para lo que se esta haciendo... creo tendrías menos problemas si los metes en un struct, asi solo tendrás un solo arreglo con ambas propiedades...

Answer (score 0):

esto es mas una recomendación..... en estos arreglos:

> ```
> var arrPageTitle: NSArray = NSArray()
> var arrPagePhoto: NSArray = NSArray()
> ```

esto lo puedes reemplazar por un

> ```
> var structContent: [StructContent]?
> ```

tu estructura asi....

```
struct StructContent {
      let image: String
      let title: String
}
```

asi solo recorres el arreglo para pasarle a tus pages la info... ahi te tocaría implementar en que se vaya generando los pageContentController dependiendo la cantidad de items del arreglo, asi tengo yo un page dinámico donde obtengo la data desde un servicio., imagenes texto etc... como tienes dos arreglos puede que te este haciendo algo raro la ejecución no sabría con certeza. pero asi solo recorriendo uno optimizas las cosas.

```
contentStruct.forEach { item in 
    // aqui llenas los pageContents 
  }
```